# testing linear regression model efficiency

Tags: regression

I have implemented linear regression manually, for learning purposes, and I use the ["Auto MPG" data set](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Auto+MPG) as the toy data I'm applying it to.

It occured to me that I don't know how to test the efficiency of my model! With classification I can check the predicted class vs the actual class, but what do I do with regression?

**EDIT: Of course, I am splitting the data I have into train + test data...I am speaking of evaluating the results when I apply the model on the test data.**

For instance, using my model I predict 16.76 mpg for a car for which the actual value in the data set is 15.5. How do I decide whether this is a "good" or "bad" prediction?
I am thinking of using some thresholds ("if the predicted value is within the [actual-epsilon, actual+epsilon] interval => OK!"), but is this a good approach? And even if it is, how do I choose epsilon values?

I am aware of the fact that there's most likely no clear-cut answer, but any suggestion regarding the approach to take would be most helpful.

**EDIT: I've decided to go with the following approach: for each test data sample, I am computing how far the predicted value is from the test data as**

```
abs(predicted_value - actual_value) * 100 /  actual_value
```

**i.e. how far away is the prediction from the actual value, expressed in % of actual value.
Any feedback is still welcome, since this is just an idea I've had, and I'm not sure if it is "best practice".**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using RMSE (root mean square error) of your predictions on your test set when compared to the actual value. This is a standard method of reporting prediction error of a continuous variable.
You can use R^2 to examine how well your model fits the training data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, this is exactly what I was looking for! So I would do sqrt(sum((predicted_i - actual_i)^2)/#samples), where i=1..#samples?

Comment: Yes, thats correct.

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but just to double check, the RMSE is a scalar value correct? And the optimal value would be 0?

Comment: Yes. It is a scalar value. A perfectly fitted model would have RMSE of 0.